# Postgresql updating JSON column

Tags: sql, postgresql

Running into an odd issue here that I hope you may be able to help me with.

I have a query as part of a set that I want to have update however when I run the query I always get

ERROR:  invalid input syntax for type json
DETAIL:  The input string ended unexpectedly.
CONTEXT:  JSON data, line 1:
SQL state: 22P02

```
update attendee_data as t set 
                                fname = c.attendee_fname,
                                lname = c.attendee_lname,
                                title = c.attendee_title,
                                email = c.attendee_email,
                                phone = c.attendee_phone,
                                company = c.attendee_company,
                                description = c.attendee_des,
                                links = CAST(c.attendee_links AS json),
                                grouplistid = c.attendee_groups,
                                attendeeonly = c.attendee_atonly


                             from (values (' Sandy1', 'Abbot', 'Sales Rep', '', '', '', '', '', '', '[{"test":"test"}]', '')) as c(attendee_fname,attendee_lname,attendee_title,attendee_email,attendee_phone,attendee_company,attendee_des,attendee_links,attendee_groups,attendee_atonly,attendee_id)
                             where CAST (c.attendee_id AS bigint) = CAST (t.sid AS bigint) AND aid = 91848 AND cid= 84616
```

The above query is test data running directly in PG admin, not sure what I'm doing wrong here but any help would be apreciated!

Thanks.

Comment: It looks like your json string is expected in `c.attendee_links` but you have it in `c.attendee_atonly`

Comment: @clamp, My goodness... Thank you so much, one of those moments where you cant see what is right there in your face.. ugh. Had been going down a rabit hole trying to figure out why I was getting this error, again thanks a lot!